# ¿Cómo justificar el contenido de un div al centro pero que su contenido esté a la izquierda?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

Buen día comunidad,

tengo un div como contenedor flex, dentro de este div tengo Cards, el asunto es que quiero que el div esté centrado mientras su contenido se mantiene a la izquierda, de momento para centrar el div uso la propiedad

> justify-content: center

lo que centra el contenido correctamente sin embargo los objetos cuyo espacio es mayor

```
import * as React from "react";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardActions from "@mui/material/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";

let arreglo = [1, 2];

const LizardCard = () => {
  return (
    //estas son las cards, o los items del contenedor flexbox los cuales quiero que esten a la izquierda
    <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345, boxShadow: "0px 2px 5px" }}>
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="140"
        image="https://mui.com/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
        alt="green iguana"
      />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
          Lizard
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
          Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
          species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small">Share</Button>
        <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

const Test = () => {
  return (
    // Este elemento Box de material UI es solo un div.
    // Este div es el contenedor cuyo contenido necesito al centro de la página o bien al centro de otro div
    // Pero que su contenido se mantenga a la izquierda como con flex-start
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexFlow: "row wrap",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "left",
        gap: "10px",
      }}
    >
      {arreglo.map((x) => {
        return <LizardCard />;
      })}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Agrego imágenes de lo que tengo ahora, u cuál es el problema:

[image: Ejemplo del problema]

Gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Como pueden ver la última fila no tiene 3 items por lo que esa fila se centra gracias al justify content, pero si coloco justify-content: flex-start obtengo esto:
[image: Ejemplo del problema 2]

si ven los items si se van a la izquierda pero... todo el contenedor se va a la izquierda, ahi es donde probé justify-content: center, align-items: flex-start pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Podrías agregar una imagen de cómo están ahorita y cómo los deseas?

Comment: Listo, edité el post.

Comment: Entonces quieres que solo los items que tengan menos de 3 elementos se alineen a la izquierda? es decir que la primer fila quede como la primer imagen y la segunda fila quede como la segunda imagen?

Comment: Si, en ese escenario, caben 3 elementos pero esto depende de la resolución de pantalla, lo que ocurre es que al haber menos de 3 se centran junto con el contenedor. en la segunda imágen ya están a la izquierda pero el contenedor también se fue a la izquierda

Comment: prueba con: `alignItems: center;` `justifyContent: center;` `flexDirection: column;`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que los items quiero que esten desplegados N cantidad por fila no por columna, pero gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas en la que se podría hacer lo que pides, la que yo ocuparia seria agregar un div extra que se encargue que contener tu lista de elementos, a este div se encargara de centrar toda tu lista de elementos. y

```
<div
  style={{
    display:'flex',
    justify-content: 'center',
    width: '-webkit-fill-available',
  }}
>
  <Box
    sx={{
      display: "flex",
      flexFlow: "row wrap",
      justifyContent: "flex-start",
      alignItems: "left",
      gap: "10px",
    }}
  >
    {arreglo.map((x) => {
      return <LizardCard />;
    })}
  </Box>
<div>
```

De esta manera el div se encargara de centrarte la lista y el Box de alinear los elementos al principio como lo deseas.

Nota: Es solo un ejemplo, mas que nada es para que entiendas la idea y puedas implementarlo a tu manera.

Comment: Hola Aldrich, justo esto ya lo había intentado pero no funciona, siempre se va a la izquierda el contenedor.

Comment: Seguramente algo no se debe estar implementando de manera adecuada. Deberías dar mas detalles de tu problema para ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas veces en vez de poner más código es mejor depurar y quitar:

```
const Test = () => {
  return (
    // Este elemento Box de material UI es solo un div.
    // Este div es el contenedor cuyo contenido necesito al centro de la página o bien al centro de otro div
    // Pero que su contenido se mantenga a la izquierda como con flex-start
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        gap: "10px",
      }}
    >
      {arreglo.map((x) => {
        return <LizardCard />;
      })}
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).